# gnome-passwordsafe on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ppa, snap, flatpak, keepass

Are there any ways to install `gnome-passwordsafe` on Ubuntu 20.10? I have not found this package in the standard repositories, snap store contains only beta version and flatpak tries to download over 1GB data. Maybe there is some little-known repository? By the way, are there any plans to add it to standard repos in the near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gnome-passwordsafe` is [available](https://repology.org/project/gnome-passwordsafe/versions) on Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute Hippo in the Proposed repositories.